# Retrieving Clustered Datapoints and Finding Optimal Cluster Count in ML.NET

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, multiclass-classification, ml.net

I'm delving into machine learning and am currently experimenting with multiclass classification in ML.NET.

**Background:**

- I have a dataset containing financial data and I aim to infer a category from it.
- I've already tried a supervised approach which was successful.
- For comparison, I'd like to try other approaches such as unsupervised and semi-supervised techniques. I'm yet to experiment with the semi-supervised approach.
- With the unsupervised approach, my initial plan was to cluster the data using the k-Means-algorithm and then observe which datapoints reside within each cluster. Training the model and using it to predict clusters for datapoints is working as expected.

**Issues I'm Facing:**

1. Using the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.trainers.kmeansmodelparameters?view=ml-dotnet#examples), I learned how to extract the coordinates of the discovered centroids. Is there a similar way for me to extract the datapoints that were assigned to these clusters during training? Or do I need to input all my training data into the model a second time to retrieve the corresponding clusters? I do not only want to know how new data is clustered, but also how my training data was clustered. I hope that makes sense.
2. Choosing the optimal number of clusters in k-Means can be challenging. I'd like to utilize the [Silhouette method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silhouette_(clustering)) for this purpose. From my understanding, this should allow me to compare multiple models without being biased by their number of clusters (number of clusters directly influences [ClusteringMetrics.AverageDistance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.data.clusteringmetrics?view=ml-dotnet) and therefore cannot be used to compare two models with different cluster counts?). To compute the silhouette score, I need the coordinates of each datapoint as well as its assigned cluster. Is it possible to retrieve the coordinates for a particular datapoint or even for all datapoints? If that isn't possible, is there an alternative way to compare multiple models?

In general, I find the workflow of unsupervised learning in ML.NET a bit unclear. Any clarification and assistance?